# Javascript Regex into Rust regex

Tags: regex, rust

I have a Javascript regex for password validation:

```js
// Validates password with
// — No white spaces
// — At least one upper case English letter, (?=.*?[A-Z])
// — At least one lower case English letter, (?=.*?[a-z])
// — At least one digit, (?=.*?[0-9])
// — Minimum eight in length .{8,} (with the anchors)

const passwordRegex = /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{6,10}$/;
```

I am trying to translate it into Rust regex using `regex` library; but it seems that it doesn't support lookahead: https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/

```rust
use regex::Regex;

pub fn validate_password(string: &str) -> bool {
  let regex_no_whitespaces = Regex::new(r"^\s*\S+\s*$").unwrap();
  let regex_password = Regex::new(r"^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{6,10}$").unwrap();
  let password_valid = regex_password.is_match(&string);
  let password_has_no_whitespaces = regex_no_whitespaces.is_match(&string);
  let is_valid = password_valid && password_has_no_whitespaces;

  return is_valid;
}
```

What is the common way to validate a string with multiple conditions without a lookahead?

EDIT: it is possible to do it using Regex, here a version in the playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c6f69f5018e38677af1624a7bfcd186c.

```rust
pub fn validate_password(string: &str) -> bool {
  let regex_no_whitespaces = Regex::new(r"^\s*\S+\s*$").unwrap();
  let no_whitespaces = regex_no_whitespaces.is_match(&string);
  let regex_one_uppercase = Regex::new(r"[a-z]{1,}").unwrap();
  let one_uppercase = regex_one_uppercase.is_match(&string);
  let regex_one_lowercase = Regex::new(r"[A-Z]{1,}").unwrap();
  let one_lowercase = regex_one_lowercase.is_match(&string);
  let regex_one_digit = Regex::new(r"[0-9]{1,}").unwrap();
  let one_digit = regex_one_digit.is_match(&string);
  let regex_length = Regex::new(r".{8,}").unwrap();
  let length = regex_length.is_match(&string);

  let is_valid = no_whitespaces && one_uppercase && one_lowercase && one_digit && length;

  return is_valid;
}
```

But the version provided by @sirdarius is way cleaner.

Comment: You could simply use several regexps: one that asserts there's an upper-case letter, one that asserts there's a lower-case letter, one that asserts there's a digit, and one that checks the length. Or... you can do these things without using regexps in the first place? Rust is a compiled low-level language, so doing it "by hand" will be no slower than using regexps.

Comment: «you can do these things without using regexps»: interesting, how? Can you provide some example?

Comment: You can do what the answer suggests, or you can use the `all()` and `any()` iterator methods to make it even cleaner: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4aace8fe0c6792fbd3b7d5487170e4f6

Comment: That's a nice one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that does not use regular expressions.

```
fn is_password_valid(s: &str) -> bool {
    let mut has_whitespace = false;
    let mut has_upper = false;
    let mut has_lower = false;
    let mut has_digit = false;

    for c in s.chars() {
        has_whitespace |= c.is_whitespace();
        has_lower |= c.is_lowercase();
        has_upper |= c.is_uppercase();
        has_digit |= c.is_digit(10);
    }

    !has_whitespace && has_upper && has_lower && has_digit && s.len() >= 8
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=49f66b40c41422cef19dcffc459947f5)

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats great. I just wrote this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c259ba2270adb94278bcf936c280d3d2, but yours is way cleaner.

Comment: Sorry I inverted the "no whitespace" condition. Fixing it.

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed it. It works nicely, and reads better than a multiple regex version. Will use it

Comment: “If all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail.” Regexes are a nice tool, but a bit overkill for a problem like this one =)

Answer (score 0):

```rust
fn is_password_valid(password: &str) -> bool {
    let mut has_uppercase = false;
    let mut has_lowercase = false;
    let mut has_digit = false;
    let mut has_whitespace = false;
    for c in password.chars() {
        if c.is_uppercase() {
            has_uppercase = true;
        } else if c.is_lowercase() {
            has_lowercase = true;
        } else if c.is_digit(10) {
            has_digit = true;
        } else if c.is_whitespace() {
            has_whitespace = true;
        }
    }
    has_uppercase && has_lowercase && has_digit && !has_whitespace
}
```